# QRegularExpression to Strip ANSI Control Codes

Tags: regex, qt, qregexp, qregularexpression

I'm using the regular expression

> "\x1B[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]"

to strip ANSI control codes out of a string. This works just fine with sed, but if I feed that string to a QRegularExpression it fails to match the control characters. I've tried using the QRegularExpression::escape() function; tried escaping just the leading '\x1B'; tried using '\e' in its place, all to no avail.

Comment: Try declaring it as `auto re = QRegularExpression { R"\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mK]" };`. If it does not work as expected, try using `\x{1B}` instead of `\x1B`.

Comment: Please share the input string as a string literal.

Comment: Wiktor's response, using raw strings, solved the problem.

Comment: SixDegrees, I posted the answer with a bit of an explanation. Note that `[m|K]` may also match `|`.

Comment: I posted the answer below. Once you have time, please feel free to accept/upvote (you will also get 2 points for accepting a working answer).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    const char data[] = "some \x1b[31;1mtext";

    QRegularExpression re("\\x1B\\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]");
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = re.match(data);

    if (!re.isValid()) {
        std::cout << "not valid" << std::endl;
    }
    if (match.hasMatch()) {
        std::cout << "matched" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You should escape symbols like `[` (`"\\["`). You can use both `"\x1b"` and `"\\x1b"` in `QRegularExpression` (in the first case it'll be just `0x1b` symbol).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *raw string literal* and forget about the problems with escaping regex escapes:

```
auto re = QRegularExpression { R"\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mK]" };
```

Here, each `\` is treated as a literal backslash.

**Also note** that `[m|K]` matches **3** characters: `m`, `K` *and* `|`. Inside a positive character class, the characters are *OR*-ed, and `|` is parsed as a literal symbol.